# In unity how to make in-game menu?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm making a Unity2D mobile game but I'm stuck on making a menu. I want the in-game menu and if the player touches the screen or clicks the screen, the game will start and the menu will be have store, options but I don't know how to do it. I tried to do the same scene but this time when it goes to the next level, the menu disappears. I searched on the internet but couldn't find it. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide more details regarding your question? Also show us what you tried so far.

Comment: I actually deleted my code but i can provide more detail.I edited my question you can see i wanna make like this menu appers in front of the game when touch the screen or click the screen game will start. @RazvanS.

Comment: It's still unclear, but you should checkout how to use Canvas for UI. You can get details on the Unity website and other places.

Comment: Hmm okay thank you. Anyone know this how to make that at least idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first create a **UIManager** script for yourself.
In this script, you must define 2D elements such as *Text*, *Canvas*, *Panel* and provide their functionality.
Then you can control these functions in your main manager **(GameManager)**.
To put it simply, it takes almost a video tutorial to explain it.
Because this is not a simple code error question, man.

Comment: That make sense.Thank you. Do you know any tutorial about this? i searched some but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Sure no problem I search today tutorial and if find send to you